# Find line of text in relation to a video currentTime and highlight it using javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, styles

What I aim to do is have some text and using JavaScript change the colour of the text when the currentTime of the embedded video is between the start and end tags. I have some text as below, what is the best way, using JavaScript, to cycle through it and read the start and end tags?

```
<div id="transcript">
<h3>Transcript</h3>
<p class="tran">
<span tag="ID_1" start="0" end="6">transcript line #1</span>
<span tag="ID_2" start="6" end="9"> transcript line #2</span>
</p>
</div>
```

Using tutorials I have managed to hide text and show it as captions, but what I really want to do is show the full text and just highlight the current part. Using something like this below.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < transcriptlength; i++) {
 if (now >= tran.start && now <= tran.end){
 span.style.color = red; // 
 break;
 }}
```

I'm not sure if document.getElementById(transcript) would work in getting all the data. 
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do what you're after like this:

```
var lines = document.getElementById("transcript").getElementsByTagName("span"); 
var now = 4;

for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (now >= +lines[i].getAttribute("start") && 
      now <= +lines[i].getAttribute("end")) {
    lines[i].style.color = "red";
    break;
  }
}
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rNnB4/)///but since we're using invalid attributes, might as well use HTML5 valid `data-` attributes (e.g. `data-start` instead of `start`), and I'd also use a class for styling, like this:

```
for (var i = 0, l = lines.length; i < l; i++) {
  if (now >= +lines[i].getAttribute("data-start") && 
      now <= +lines[i].getAttribute("data-end")) {
    lines[i].className = "current";
  } else {
    lines[i].className = "";
  }
}
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/rNnB4/1/), it allows you to more easily style that span by simply changing the `.current` class in the CSS.  Also, as the video progresses, this will clear the styling from the previously selected element, getting the "current line" effect you're after.